# less<T> class and less than operator '<'

Tags: c++, set

In the C++ standard library set, `less<T>` is default functor used for the comparison. But whenever we make some user-defined data type(say using struct) and also overloads the less than operator '<' than there is no issue faced while making a set of our customized data type.

So my question is that since the set uses `less<T>` as default for comparison then why there is no issue once we overload the '<' less-than operator. what is the connection between '<' and less? I can understand that there will be no issue if we define a functor for our user-defined data type but I am not able to understand that why does it work out by overloading '<' operator.

And please bear my one follow up question with this that whenever creating a set for the user-defined data type, which is considered a good practice to overload a '<' operator or to define our own functor and pass it as a template parameter. for example:

```
set<my_type,mycompar> myset
```

Answer (score 3):

> what is the connection between '<' and less?

From the reference for [std::less](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less):

> Function object for performing comparisons. Unless specialized, invokes `operator<` on type T.

So `std::less` is defined in terms of `operator<`. So long as you can compare objects of your type with `operator<`, that's what `std::less` will use.

---

> whenever creating a set for the user-defined data type, which is considered a good practice to overload a '<' operator or to define our own functor and pass it as a template parameter?

This depends on the use case. If `operator<` makes sense for the type, then you should define it for that type.

If `operator<` doesn't generally make sense, but is useful for some particular algorithm where you're using the `set`, then pass in a comparison object for that specific purpose.